# Adding values on XOR for Checksum

Tags: c#

On the internet the rules says for XOR it becomes one if one value is 0 and another is 1. I got that point so:

```
0 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 1

0 0 0 1 1
```

What I don't get is how come when I add

```
23
12

31
```

How did it come up with 31?

Comment: `23 ^ 12 == 27` (or `10111 ^ 01100 == 11011` in binary); however `23 | 12 == 31`, haven't you mixed **xor** (exclusive or) and just an **or** (if you are sure in the `31`)?

Comment: Your first snippet is not an XOR

Comment: Bigiansen is right, `0 XOR 0` is `0`, not `1`

Comment: I'm sorry. I copied the wrong line. Please let me correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I suspect is the following:

`23` is actually `2` followed with `3`
`12` is actually `1` followed with `2`
In binary:
`2 3` -> `10 11`
`1 2` -> `01 10`

`XOR` gives you:
`11 01` -> `3 1`

---

Edit:

As suggested in comments, it could also be that you used `OR` instead of `XOR`:

```
10111 // 23
01100 // 12
11111 // 31
```

Comment: Thank you. That made sense.